# Метод покоординатного спуска на Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, функции, математика

Есть функция

```
def f(x, y):
  return (5 * (1 - x)) / (7.88 * (1 - y))
```

Для задачи одномерной оптимизации использую метод золотого сечения.
Нужно найти такие x и y, чтобы возвращаемое значение было минимальным.
x, y из отрезка [0.0001, 0.9999]
Можно пример, как такое реализуется по-человечески?

Comment: Непонятно, что нужно. Это реализация какого-то математического алгоритма? Добавьте, например, входные данные и ожидаемый результат. А что у вас не получилось, приведите код с попыткой, чтобы проще был помочь :)

Comment: Мне просто нужно найти такие х и у, чтобы получить минимальное значение f(x, y) при помощи метода покоординатного спуска.

Comment: [первая ссылка из гугла](http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) по запросу «метод покоординатного спуска»... что именно не понятного в том как это реализовать по-человечески?

Comment: Что значит приближенного значения. Как задаётся сам цикл с остановкой. И как именно фиксируются значения. Я просто даже не знаю с чего мне начать реализацию.

Comment: «Что значит приближенного значения» — не распарсил...

Comment: "Как задаётся сам цикл с остановкой". -  после этой фразы возник вопрос: А вы с синтаксисом Python знакомы?  Что, и понятие "приближенного значения" вам незнакомы ? А кроме того, фраза "фиксируются значения"  -  вводит в ступор. Что, кем и зачем должно фиксироваться? Попробуйте свой вопрос переформулировать четко и конкретно, в понятных всем терминах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Общее описание алгоритма легко находится [по первой ссылке](http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) в гугле:

1. Инициализация некоторым значением x_0
2. повторять:
   для i=1…n

   1. фиксируем значения всех переменных кроме *x<sub>i</sub>*, получая одномерную функцию *f(x<sub>i</sub>)*
   2. проводим одномерную оптимизацию по переменной *x<sub>i</sub>*, любым методом одномерной оптимизации
   3. если выполнен критерий останова, то возвращаем текущее значение x=(x<sub>1</sub>,…,x<sub>n</sub>)

> Как именно фиксируются значения.

В общем многомерном случае, у нас есть *F(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>n</sub>)*. Изначально мы выбираем какое-нибудь произвольное значение вектора *X⁰(x⁰<sub>1</sub>, ... x⁰<sub>n</sub>), например, в середине области.

На первой итерации (*i=1*) мы фиксируем все значения кроме *x<sub>1</sub>*, по сути подставляем их в функцию и рассмaтриваем её как функцию одной переменной: *f(x<sub>1</sub>) = F(x<sub>1</sub>, x⁰<sub>2</sub>, ... x⁰<sub>n</sub>)*. И применяем к ней метод одномерной оптимизации, например, метод золотого сечения.

Полученный результат одномерной оптимизации заменяет *x<sub>1</sub>* в векторе *X⁰*. Так получаем вектор *X¹*. Остальные значения не меняются.

Далее для вектора *X¹* проделываем аналогичные манипуляции с x<sub>2</sub> и т.д. Когда дойдём до переменной x<sub>n</sub>, снова надо начать с x<sub>1</sub>.

Для двумерного случая `f(x,y)`, *x1* — это *x*. x2 — это *y*. т.е. сначала применяешь метод одномерной оптимизации по *x*, затем по *y*, затем снова по *x* и т.д.

> Как задаётся сам цикл с остановкой.

Выбирается один из критериев останова, например что на *i+1*-м шаге функция отличается от того что было на *i*-м меньше чем на малую величину `epc`.

Условие выхода можно проверять как и после оптимизации по каждой координате так и после одного шага оптимизации по всем координатам. В первом случае будет обычный цикл `while`, а во-втором — цикл `while` со вложенным циклом `for` по переменным. Для двух переменных его вполне можно развернуть.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Всё получилось в итоге